# Angular 2 - Can't get url from router

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I can't get the url when I use `console.log(_router.url)`. It only returns a `/` (slash)

When I do the below code:

```
constructor(
    private el: ElementRef,
    private _auth:AuthenticationService,
    @Inject(AppStore) private store: Store<AppState>,
    private _router:Router,
  ) {

    console.log(_router);
    console.log(_router.url);
  }
```

This is the result of `console.log(_router)`
[image]

when (...) is clicked it displays `"/languages"`

[image]

but when I `console.log(_router.url)` this is only it prints

[image]

Comment: Did you get this solved. The answer doesn't seems to be working for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always try to get the route from the location service

```
constructor(location: Location) {
  console.log(location.path());
}
```

[Location docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/Location-class.html)

Answer (score 2):

@Owain van Brakel's answer is correct but missing some details, I couldn't use this.router.url(as suggested in other answers in StackOverflow) so I used location.path(), the outcome is similar.

This is my code:

```
// This is important because when you use Location in the constructor it
// gets accepted but the wrong library is used. 
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

export class MainComponent {
   constructor(public location: Location) {
      console.log(this.location.path());
   }
}
```